# About the choice of preposition in “être + adjective + à/de quelque chose”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

- être égal/équivalent à quelque chose
- être différent de quelque chose

Why are the prepositions different? Do these follow a rule? Something similar happens in phrases like

- avoir envie de faire quelque chose
- avoir du mal à faire quelque chose

Comment: I'm afraid there's no rule, you have to learn which preposition introduces the object after an intransitive  verb, or which preposition to use after such or such a phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, **à** means *to*, *at*, or *in*, while **de** means *of* or *from*.

1. **être** égal/équivalent **à** quelque chose
   to be equal **to** something ✓
   to be equal **from** something ✗
2. **être** différent **de** quelque chose
   to be different **to/in/at** something ✗
   to be different **from** something ✓

There are many exceptions. But in general, this rule will work. Fore more info (in french) : http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-3219.php

Answer (score 1):

Being French, I know this can be confusing. You can't find real equivalent in English. The thing is that the prepositions depend on the adjectives following the verb, i.e., in that case *être* or *avoir* do not determined the prepositions you are going to use. You have to look at the adjective following the verb to know. My advice would be to look at the adjective in a French dictionnary to find how to use it according to the context.

You also have to take care because it is different when there is no adjective in between.

Here is the link for a very French dictionnary which gives you general rules and example:

http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-monolingue

Answer (score 0):

One explanation can be found in: 
Henri Adamczweski (1991), pp 65-81, *Le Français déchiffré* ([Here is a scan](http://www.quivy.org/adam.pdf)).

Consult, and check back on, [this question of me](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/20262/1995).