# As of December 2019, is there any new and improved linguistics research on « à » vs « de » ?

Tags: prépositions, ressources

Because later works probably ameliorate and supersede earlier works, I cite only articles published after 2005 that I have encountered through Google. Because the papers below have extensive bibliographies and citations, I will remove any suggestion that already appears therein.

[[First suggested here:]](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17695/1995) Henri Adamczweski (1991), *Le Français déchiffré* ([Here is a scan](http://www.quivy.org/adam.pdf)).

[FRACZAK, Lidia (2008)](http://lrl.univ-bpclermont.fr/article268.html), *French prepositions à and de in infinitival complements : A pragma-semantic analysis*, in Kurzon, D. & Adler, S. (eds), *Adpositions : Pragmatic, semantic and syntactic perspectives*, Typological Studies in Language, 74, John Benjamins Publishing Company, Amsterdam, Philadelphia, 171-190 (https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00910810/). ([Related articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=French+prepositions+%C3%A0+and+de+in+infinitival+complements&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=))

[Christiane Marque-Pucheu](http://www.paris-sorbonne.fr/MARQUE-PUCHEU-Christiane?lettre=m) (2008), [*La couleur des prépositions à et de*](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2008-1-page-74.htm). ([Cited articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=393307087656539836&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en))

Comment: You can also turn it around by checking which works or articles *cite* those you refer to (e.g., like [this](https://scholar.google.be/scholar?cites=393307087656539836&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) although I'd also check a few others besides Google Scholar).

Comment: Ahh.... La maison de Pierre ou la maison à pierre. Question que j'ai trouvé un jour (avec mêmes les majuscules/minuscules) dans Rablais.

Comment: La question est beaucoup trop large pour espérer avoir une réponse sérieuse. Si vous avez une question précise, posez la. Ou faites une synthèse de vos interrogations. Se contenter de poster deux pointeurs sur des articles de près de 30 pages... c'est un peu court.

Comment: @AlainD – Rabelais peut-être ? Quant à « La maison de Pierre ou la maison à Pierre », ces tournures sont toutes deux issues du bas-latin, mais le français « reconnu » a préféré « de » pour exprimer le génitif, « à » fait euh populaire et pour ainsi dire peu évolué ou peu éduqué.

Comment: La maison à brique ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at (it is not official research but may be useful) :

- [Il participe «à» ou «de»: ne faites plus la faute !](http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2018/05/31/37003-20180531ARTFIG00033-il-participe-a-ou-de-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php) (in French)
- [À vs. De: French Prepositions](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/a-vs-de/) (in English)
- [Préposition : La canne À ou DE Jules ? - cours](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-8878.php) (in French)

You may also do some training [here](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-107599.php)